# Android Studio recognizes physical device, but won't run app on it

Tags: android-studio, nexus-7

I have an app developed under Android Studio that used to run fine on my Nexus 7 when I connected it to my PC via USB.  Now Android Studio still recognizes the Nexus 7; I see it in the Android Device Manager; it's labelled online and I can push and pull files, so I know there's a bona fide connection.  But when I click the run button, an emulator opens up...the app never runs on the physical device.

There are lots of similar looking questions here, but they're mostly cases in which Android Studio doesn't recognize a device or fails to show it as online.

Why is my app not running on a recognized, online physical device?  And what can I do to get Android Studio to use my Nexus 7 rather than an emulator?

Comment: Does the app get installed? If it does, I think you will need to fix the run configuration of your project. Click on the "app" (or whatever your main module or project is named) near that play-button, and see what is the default Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the emulator straight away is a preset option, you must have agreed to it earlier and forgot about it. I don't have studio open in front of me, but if I recall correctly you should be able to open `AVD Manager` and change it there. If not move into your `Build Settings` and take that preset off. Hope this helps!

Comment: Found it under Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Target Device.  Thanks.